# jQuery get a random line from text file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, random

I have a .txt file, with around 754 lines. Each line has a pattern like this:

> 1st part text#2nd part text#3rd part text or number

The hashtag is the delimiter!

What I'm trying to do is to get() or read() this text file, and retrieve a random line from it, with all the pattern.
But it has to be a random line.
So I can print it or append html to a div. It should look something like this:

- 1st part from a line
- 2nd part from the same line
- 3rd part from the same line

It has this pattern, because maybe I'll have to retrieve only one part of the pattern.

I don't know if a text file is the right type of file to pull data from.... But its only 80kb.
There is any way to do this? Could someone give me a hand? I'm actually a designer, this thing is driving me crazy.

What I got... Trying to count how many lines the txt have, so I can get a random line. It doesn't work. Does the text file must have \n on the end of each line?

```
$.get('txt/messages.txt', function(txt) {
    var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
        save(lines[i]);
    }
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.11.1, and jQuery mobile 1.4.4

Comment: `txt` itself is the `responseText` of the request, remove the `responseText` property.

Comment: Aren't you getting errors in the Javascript console? Don't you know that you should use the Javascript console when you're trying to debug a Javascript problem? http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is example of how to pull out a random line from the txt response:

```
$.get('txt/messages.txt', function(txt) {
    var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
    var randLineNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines.length);
    save(lines[randLineNum]); // random line from the text file
});
```

From there you can split that line based on the delimeter (`#`):

```
lines[randLineNum].split("#");
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdaverde/2sewruu4/)example. Hope this helps!